# How to delete cache (js/css/fonts) with htaccess - using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, create-react-app, browser-cache

I created a React App with `create-react-app` months ago. For better performances I searched and found things to add to my `.htaccess` to cache css, fonts and js files.
Here's a preview of my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

<filesMatch ".(woff|woff2|ico|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff2
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

It's working pretty well. But the issue is : when I edit content (or whatever) on my React application, the browser still displays the older content. I think it's normal because of the code inside the `.htaccess`. But I'm looking for a solution that could remove the old version of my Application for all browsers and display the new version without removing the cache manually. Is that possible ?

Precision : Sorry, I don't have any experience in servers, or back-end development.

Thanks !

Lucie

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Once a resource _has_ been cached by the client, there is little you can do about it afterwards. The usual solution to this is to change the URLs of your embedded assets. Even a small thing like appending a random / time-dependent GET parameter will do, keyword "cache buster."

Comment: Hi CBroe, that's the first thing I tried. As I don't know how to change the URLs, I re-created a new React App (with create-react-app), copied all my new code inside it, and build it. But the browser still has the old version of the website (except if I open it in incognito session).